# VB.NET and dsmod

Tags: vb.net, cmd

I have a question.
I'm trying to change an AD user password in cmd with vb.net
My command:

```
dsmod user "CN=admin,OU=Admins,OU=Users,DC=DOMAIN,DC=LOCAL" -pwd test1
```

In a regular cmd not as admin (WIN+R - cmd) it works perfectly

```
dsmod succeeded:CN=admin,OU=Admins,OU=Users,DC=DOMAIN,DC=LOCAL
```

But when I run the same command through vb.net:

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/k dsmod user " & """" & "CN=admin,OU=Admins,OU=Users,DC=DOMAIN,DC=LOCAL" & """" & " -pwd " & TextBox1.Text & """")
```

I get:

```
'dsmod' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How can I fix this?
Thanks

Comment: It is the kind of command that tends to be only available as a 64-bit program.  Project > Properties > Compile tab, untick the "Prefer 32-bit" checkbox.  The docs do mention that UAC elevation is required, https://stackoverflow.com/a/2818776/17034

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default any process you start through `Process.Start()` gets the same working directory as your application. The `dsmod.exe` file is most likely located in `System32`, so you've got to set the new process's working directory to that in order for it to find the file.

```
Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/k dsmod user " & """" & "CN=admin,OU=Admins,OU=Users,DC=DOMAIN,DC=LOCAL" & """" & " -pwd " & TextBox1.Text)
psi.WorkingDirectory = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows), "System32")

Process.Start(psi)
```

I also took the liberty of removing the extra double quote you put at the end of the arguments since it had no matching starting quote.

**NOTE:** Since the system folder might be located on a different drive than the `C:\` drive, I used this code:

```
Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows), "System32")
```

in order to dynamically get the `System32` folder of the current system. So for instance if the system drive has the letter `D:\`, this code will return `D:\Windows\System32`.

---

**EDIT:**

It appears that `dsmod` is only available in the 64-bit system directory. If your application is a 32-bit app it will also start a 32-bit version of CMD (located in `SysWOW64`), so you've got to force it to open the 64-bit version that's located in the `System32` directory. To do this you've got to specify the full path of CMD, but in the `Sysnative` directory.

By specifying `Sysnative` instead of `System32` you stop the system from redirecting you to the `SysWOW64` directory for your 32-bit app.

```
Dim CmdPath As String = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows), If(Environment.Is64BitProcess OrElse Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem = False, "System32", "Sysnative"), "cmd.exe")

Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo(CmdPath, "/k dsmod user " & """" & "CN=admin,OU=Admins,OU=Users,DC=DOMAIN,DC=LOCAL" & """" & " -pwd " & TextBox1.Text)
psi.WorkingDirectory = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows), "System32")

Process.Start(psi)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I do get System32 as the working directory, but I still get the same error...

Comment: That worked, Thanks! Until I saw this answer I found a shorter and simpler way to do this (with PowerShell) it is only 2 lines...  Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo("powershell.exe", "$newpwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String " & """" & TextBox1.Text & """" & " -AsPlainText –Force ; Set-ADAccountPassword admin -NewPassword $newpwd –Reset") and 2nd line Dim process As Process = Process.Start(psi)... But thanks for the reply...

Comment: @user7406533 : Glad I could help! I intentionally made my solution longer so that it would be easier to read.

Comment: @user7406533 : Actually you can shorten that solution of yours to one line: `Dim p As Process = Process.Start("powershell.exe", "$newpwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String " & """" & TextBox1.Text & """" & " -AsPlainText –Force ; Set-ADAccountPassword admin -NewPassword $newpwd –Reset")` (remove `Dim p As Process` if you don't need access to it after starting it)

Comment: BTW, (I know this is not vb related) in both cmd and PS after changing the password, the user is still accessible with the old password until you enter the user with the new password...

Comment: @user7406533 : I don't work with Active Directory so I wouldn't know. Though I did manage to find [this](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/214779-ad-accounts-can-log-in-with-two-passwords-after-a-pw-change) and [this](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPREK_9.0.2/com.ibm.isam.doc/wrp_config/reference/ref_pw_change_issue_ad_win.html). If you don't seem to be able to find a solution you might wanna ask on either [Super User](https://superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com).